# turn kendo listview into a panelbar

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a page with a kendo listview that renders UL with LI for each item. I'm trying to turn that listview into a panelbar to achieve an accordion effect where only one of the items of the list is expanded. There is no visible effect from the following code:

```
$("#myList").kendoPanelBar({
    expandMode: "single"
});
```

Has anyone turned a listview into a panelbar?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully changed a listview into a panelbar by doing so in the listview [dataBound event](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/listview#events-dataBound), like so:

```
<ul id="listView"></ul>
<script>
    $("#listView").kendoListView({
        template: "<li>#: name# <div>Age: #: age#</div></li>",
        dataSource: [
            { name: "John Doe", age: 30 },
            { name: "Jane Doe", age: 29 }
        ],
        dataBound: function() {
            $("#listView").kendoPanelBar({
                expandMode: "single"
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```